# CSS: How to make selectable boxes?

Tags: javascript, css

Say I have a 200x200 image. Then say I want to have a "box" starting at the coordinates 20px by 20px all the way to 50px by 50px (basically, a 30x30 box). I want users to be able to "select" this 30x30 box, like the way GMail's PDF viewer allows user to select boxes containing text.

In this box, I want to put text -- but I don't want this text to be selectable (thus, allowing users to select individual characters, etc.). I only want the containing box to be selectable -- and when user copies, they copy the text inside.

Is this possible in CSS? If so, how?

Comment: Tagged `javascript`, you're going to need some JS for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible with css, you will to manipulate images using javascript. Have a look at jquery and the plugins available, ou may find something that can style up checkboxes to suit your requirements.